# A Random walk with gaussian step

Tags: random

```
P = 1;
For[iter = 1, iter < 13, iter++, sigma = 1;
 a = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, sigma], 500];
 Clear[theta, x];
 theta[i_] := theta[i] = theta[i - 1] + a[[i]];
 x[i_] := x[i] = x[i - 1] + P {Cos[theta[i]], Sin[theta[i]]};
 theta[0] = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}];
 x[0] = {0, 0};
 For[step = 1, step < 500, step++, r[iter, step] = x[step];]]
Show@Table[
  ListLinePlot[Table[r[s, i], {i, 500}], PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][s],
    PlotRange -> 35
      {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {s, 1, 12}]
```

This is my attempt to generate 12 families of a two-dimensional walk.
I want to find the length of each random walk.
Should I use "Length" function?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Replace  `step < 500` to `step < =500` and use `Table[Sum[Norm[r[s, i]], {i, 1, 500}], {s, 1, 12}]`

Comment: As every step is of length: 1, the length is simply the number of steps. Or do you mean "length" to be the distance from the origin?

Comment: You can use [`AnglePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath.html) to simplify constructing the walk. e.g. `ListLinePlot[Table[AnglePath[RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 500]], 12]]`.